# Auto create queue on the non @Primary

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am working on RabbitMQ using spring.

I have 2 different virtualhost, one called as **d** and **p** .

inside **d** code, it has the @Primary annotation.

In **p** code, I have auto create the queue using QueueBuilder. When I start the spring application, I noticed that the newQueue is created in the **d** virtual-host intead. How can I make the newQueue, auto creation queue, to be created in the **p** virtual-host?

Here is the **d** configuration

```
package com.example.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="d.spring.rabbitmq")
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    private String addresses;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int port;
    private String virtualHost;

    @Bean(name="dRabbitConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(){
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

        connectionFactory.setAddresses(addresses);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="dRabbitMessageConverter")
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean(name="dRabbitTemplate")
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(@Qualifier("dRabbitConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="dRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, @Qualifier("dRabbitConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here is the **p** configuration

```
package com.example.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.QueueBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="p.spring.rabbitmq")
public class RabbitMQPConfig {
    private String addresses;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int port;
    private String virtualHost;

    @Bean(name="pRabbitConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(){
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

        connectionFactory.setAddresses(addresses);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="pRabbitMessageConverter")
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean(name="pRabbitTemplate")
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(@Qualifier("pRabbitConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="pRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, @Qualifier("pRabbitConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Value("${p.new-queue}")
    private String newQueue;

    @Bean //**this is the issue**
    Queue createNewQueue(){
        return QueueBuilder.durable(newQueue).quorum().build();
    }
}
```

here is the application.properties

```
d.spring.rabbitmq.addresses=localhost
d.spring.rabbitmq.password=
d.spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
d.spring.rabbitmq.username=
d.spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=d

p.spring.rabbitmq.addresses=localhost
p.spring.rabbitmq.password=
p.spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
p.spring.rabbitmq.username=
p.spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=p


p.new-queue=p-new-queue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a RabbitAdmin that uses the other connection factory and configure the queue so that it is only declared by that admin and not the auto-configured `amqpAdmin`.

```java
@Bean
AmqpAdmin otherAdmin(ConnectionFactory pRabbitConnectionFactory) {
    return new RabbitAdmin(pRabbitConnectionFactory);
}

@Bean
Queue createNewQueue(RabbitAdmin otherAdmin) {
    Queue q = QueueBuilder.durable(newQueue).quorum().build();
    q.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(otherAdmin);
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the solution. Is there any other way?

Comment: You could declare the queues yourself and not use the framework for that.